# MP4 videos started playing instead of downloading in HTML5 web app

Tags: html, video, download

I have a HTML5 web application in which there is a form through which user submit the video and format they want to download. On form submission, the response return the requested video format URL and the download starts automatically.

Returned Video URL are not pointing to the resource directly. Instead it has redirection to the resource.

This is working fine for FLV files but not for MP4 files.

For FLV file download starts without any problem. But in case of MP4 files, a player is launching to play it.

This behavior is same for without redirected resource URL.

Below code is auto-generating for MP4 video on receiving response:

```
<video autoplay="" controls="" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%"></video>
```

Please provide any solution to stop loading of the player and initiate the download in case of MP4 videos.
I don't control the resource server.

Comment: You need a `Content-Disposition: attachment` http header or to change the response mimetype.

Comment: I am using iframe techinque to initiate download

Comment: That's nice :). Doesn't change what you need to do though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AD7six is quit right but I would also change the content type:

```
   Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

If you use both it'll work across browsers... The disposition header also allows you to specify a name for the to be downloaded file in case you want to change that or if you download through a PHP file

Comment: Sad part is that I don't control the resource server. To initiate download I am using Iframes. Is there any solution to restrict the formation of video tags? I am aware of all the three popular techniques about forcing download. But out of them only Iframe technique I can apply here which is failing :(

Comment: Nope. If you cannot get the owner to help you, your project should be reconsidered...

Comment: Actually they are using the same server to stream videos therefore they don't want to change anything (might break something) and they have different developer team for that :(

Comment: They could use symbolic links to include the video directory inside another directory which automatically sends other headers. Another solution is to attach a variable to the URL and filter for that in the server config to send other headers

Comment: Let me suggest them your solution.. :)

Answer (score 0):

From [this article](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/forcing-file-downloads-in-php):

```
<?php
$file = "filename.ext";

// Quick check to verify that the file exists
if( !file_exists($file) ) die("File not found");

// Force the download
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="" . basename($file) . """);
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream;");
readfile($file);
?>
```